# Laravel 5 Queued Command

Tags: php, laravel, command, queue, laravel-5

I'm making a app using Laravel 5, at the moment I'm with a little problem (I hope).
So I coded a Command that implements ShouldBeQueued like this :

```
class ImportDataCommand extends Command implements SelfHandling,ShouldBeQueued {


    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public $filePath;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($filePath)
    {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
        Log::info('queued shit from command contructor and i have this destinationPath => '.$filePath);//working
        echo "contructor ".$this->filePath;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {


        $destinationPath = storage_path().'/app/gtfs/';


        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        echo "handle ".$this->filePath;
        /*$res = $zip->open($destinationPath.$this->filePath);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($destinationPath.'extracted/');
            $zip->close();
            echo 'done';

        } else {

            echo 'fail';

        }*/
    }

}
```

And I'm calling it this way:

```
$bus->dispatch(new ImportDataCommand($fileName));
```

My problem is when the command is executed after being in the queue(btw I'm using `beanstalkd`) it throws an exception because `filePath` is not set, and I think I have understood why that is happening, the command is instantiated when I sent it to the queue on the `busDispatcher` with my variable but when `handle()` is called on the queue side it doesn't send that. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the rabbit: I totally forgot about flushing all jobs each try, so I can't see why but it was messing with the Command (iIhave rebooted the Vagrant machine to but I don't think that have affected anything).

Answer (score 1):

You assign `$this->filePath` in constructor and then override it in `handle()` method.

Comment: sorry it was a typo fixed now

Comment: if i run it exactly as it is now i get  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Cannot access empty property

Comment: when i tell artisan to run the queued job **php artisan queue:work**

Comment: echo "handle ".$this->filePath;

Comment: Do you also have an error if you assign something before `echo "handle ".$this->filePath;`?